# Google news. simple_html_dom

Tags: php

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://news.google.com/news/feeds?hl=en&gl=ca&q=love&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss');

// Find all article blocks
foreach($html->find('channel->item') as $article) {
    $item['title']    = $article->find('title', 0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item;
}

  echo "$item[title]";
?>
```

Что я делаю ни так? Выводит только один title... И мне бы хотелось, чтобы сам выставлял список вывода например от 1 до 5. Помогите

Comment: у гугла вроде на NEWS есть API. чем они вам не нравятся и не подходят?)

Comment: Что-то я не нашел этого

Comment: "The Google News Search API has been officially _deprecated_ as of May 26, 2011."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите [вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900065/html-dom-parser-in-php), там как раз Simple HTML Dom и Google News, или [уже готовый](http://blog.bigtreeworld.com/209-simple-google-news-parser-in-php) парсер.

Comment: Готовый вариант я этот тоже нашел, но потом там банят чтоли(( через какое-то время

Comment: @jikol, через RSS тоже могут вполне забанить, используйте какой нибудь скрипт RSS парсинга (eg. http://codingtools.ru/lessons/3/103) и допустим, ленту РИА Новости или того же Google News

Comment: Вот, через какое то время получается так
https://news.google.com/news/feeds?hl=en&amp;gl=ca&amp;q=love&amp;um=1&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;output=rss&quot

как убрать этот (amp;)

Comment: @jikol, делаете replace

Answer (score 2):

> Что я делаю ни так? Выводит только один title...

Выводите только один title, как ни странно. Сохраненные (не очень правильно, ну да php и не такое ест) записи валяются в `$articles`, соответственно надо пройтись по ним foreach'м и вывести для каждой содержимое элемента 'title'.

**Обновление**

Фанфары, блестки, хлопушки, въезжают праздные три строчки кода, вирбельбанк в рояле нежно вибрирует:

```
foreach ($articles as $item) {
    echo $item['title'];
}
```

(при желании сработает даже двумя строчками)

```
foreach ($articles as $item)
    echo $item['title'];
```

Comment: Можете в примере показать?

Comment: Спасибо, а как вывести атрибуты link  и тд?

Comment: @jikol, очевидно, по аналогии. Я не работал с этой библой, но 99% что так

    foreach ($html->find('channel->item') as $article) {
        $item = array(
            'title' => $article->find('title', 0)->plaintext,
            'link' => $article->find('link', 0)->plaintext,
        );
        $articles[] = $item;
    }

Попробуйте в следующий раз разобрать код сами.